# return true if every property on `obj` is the same

Tags: javascript

How to check if every property on object is the same recursively in JavaScript

```
{  
   a:1,
   b 1,
   c:{  
      aa:1,

   },
};
```

would be `true`
if we replaced `aa: 1` with `aa: 2` we'd want to return `false`.

Comment: Write a recursive function that loops through all the properties, checking if they're the same as an input value.

Comment: It's not really true, as `c` is not `1`, but an object. So do you just want to look for primitives then?

Comment: ```const checkMatchingLeaves = (obj) => {
  obj = Object.values;
  obj.forEach((value) => {
    if (typeof Object(value) === 'object') return true;
  });```
}; I hav tried this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for checking the value, because the value is kind of backtracked to the calling function by using a reference.

The value to check is wrapped in an object, which allows to use it in all recursive called functions, even in the first, where no real value is first available, because of having objects with nested properties.

At the first call `value` is checked and if falsey, then it is initialised with an object. If the first real value is found, then it is used as kind of back propagation with an object and it can be used in any running calls of `check`.

[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is used,

> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

to exit early if a value does not match the first found value. Thi is the exit condition for the callback and the value to give back.

```js
function check(object, value) {
    value = value || {};
    return Object.keys(object).every(function (k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            return check(object[k], value);
        }
        if (!('value' in value)) {
            value.value = object[k];
            return true;
        }
        return object[k] === value.value;
    });
}

console.log(check({ a: 1, b: 1, c: { aa: 1 } }));
console.log(check({ a: { x: 1 }, b: 1, c: { aa: 1 } }));
console.log(check({ a: 1, b: 1, c: { aa: 2 } }));
```

Comment: Could you explain about `value || {}` and `every` method

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, just iterating recursively with an IIFE, and putting all the values in an array, and then comparing them

```js
var obj = {  
   a: 1,
   b: 1,
   c:{  
      aa:1
   }
};

function isAllSame(o) {
  var values = [];

  (function rec(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') return rec(obj[key]);
      values.push(obj[key])
    })  
  })(o);

  return values.every( x => values[0] === x);
}

console.log( isAllSame(obj) );
```

Answer (score 0):

*works now

```
          var obj = {  
           a: 1,
           b: 1,
           c:{  
           aa:1
          }
         };

             function checkifEqual(var object, var recent)
            {
             for( var x = 0; x < object.length; x++)
            {
               if(x == 0 && recent == null)
                {
                  recent = object[x];
                  continue;
                }
              if( typeof(object[x]) !== 'object' && object[x] == recent)
              {

                 continue;
              }
              else if(typeof(object[x]) === 'object')
              { 
                 if( checkifEqual(object[x],recent))
                    {
                          continue;  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return false;
                    }

              }
             else
             {
              return false;
             }
            }
          return true;
      }

      console.log(checkifEqual(obj,null));
```

on first call you would pass checkifEqual(Object,null)